# How to combine separate maven modules under a single parent module?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have module a, b and c. I want to combine b and c to be sub-modules within a and I also want to convert the code in a to be a submodule as well. How can I achieve this?

We are using intellij and maven.

Comment: It would help if you would provide some code with what you already tried and what you mean by ‚convert the code in a to be a submodule‘. Should a be the parent or a submodule or do you wanna split it up into both? Maybe you wanna check the Maven documentation https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: You want to convert a to be a submodule of what?

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand, I think you will have to make "A" a parent project of packaging type *pom* and then pull out all the code in A and move it to another project lets say A1, and then make A1, B and C as modules in your parent project A. Hope this helps.